# Full image source concatenation in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, string-concatenation

How do I get full image source (like "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/1") by concatenation of partial source:

```
var url = "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/"
```

and numbers from array

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5];
```

I already have list of images

```
<ul id="imageList"></ul>
```

I want to append images like this

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
$('#imageList').append('<li><img class="imageClass" src = "url + 'arr[i]'" /></li>');
}
```

Here source concat. is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you did not use `url` and `arr[i]` as a variable by closing the string before concatenating the variables with a `+`.

```
.append('<li><img class="imageClass" src="' + url + arr[i] + '" /></li>');
```

If you have a text editor that highlights your code for you, `url` and `arr[i]` should be in a different colour.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/WLv6F/

Answer (score 2):

You can set the `src` of the [image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement) using JavaScript:

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5];
var url = "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/" + arr[0];

var img = document.createElement('img');
img.className = 'imageClass';
img.src = url;
```

By looping through your array elements, you can append them to your list. Here I show two methods of looping: [`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and also a `for` loop if that's what you prefer:

```
var url = "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/";
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], img, listItem;

// Using foreach
arr.forEach(function(id) {
    listItem = document.createElement('li');
    img = document.createElement('img');
    img.className = 'imageClass';
    img.src = url + id;

    listItem.appendChild(img);

    document.getElementById('imageList').appendChild(listItem);
});

// Using for
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
    listItem = document.createElement('li');
    img = document.createElement('img');
    img.className = 'imageClass';
    img.src = url + arr[i];

    listItem.appendChild(img);

    document.getElementById('imageList').appendChild(listItem);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
"src = '" + url + arr[0] + "'/>"
```

Edit:

He has it wrong with:

```
'<li><img class="imageClass" src = "url + 'arr[i]'" /></li>'
```

It should be:

```
'<li><img class="imageClass" src = "' + url + arr[i] + '" /></li>'
```

Comment: Could you please add explanation to why this is good solution to the problem.